# Cropping multiple objects on single canvas with Fabric js

Tags: javascript, image, fabricjs, crop

I've been scouring the web trying to find a solution about cropping multiple images/objects on a canvas with Fabric JS.

The only solution I found was to set clipTo to null when selecting different objects. This action would undo the crop on the first object and allow cropping on second object.

The ideal would be to crop one object and for this object to remain cropped while the second object is manipulated.

The code I'm working on appears below and if anyone has any suggestions to address this challenge, I would be most appreciative.

Crop Code Using Fabric JS

```
function startCropRect(){
    canvas.remove(el);
    if(canvas.getActiveObject()) {  
        object=canvas.getActiveObject();     
        if (lastActive && lastActive !== object) {
            lastActive.clipTo = null;
        }   
        el = new fabric.Rect({
            fill: 'transparent',
            originX: 'left',
            originY: 'top',
            stroke: '#ccc',
            strokeDashArray: [2, 2],
            opacity: 1,
            width: 1,
            height: 1,
            borderColor: '#36fd00',
            cornerColor: 'green',
            hasRotatingPoint:false,
            objectCaching: false
        });  
        el.left=canvas.getActiveObject().left;
        el.top=canvas.getActiveObject().top;
        el.width=canvas.getActiveObject()
            .width*canvas.getActiveObject().scaleX;
        el.height=canvas.getActiveObject()
            .height*canvas.getActiveObject().scaleY;    
        canvas.add(el);
        canvas.setActiveObject(el);
    }  else {
      alert("Please select an object or layer");
    }
}
function endCropRect(){
    var left = el.left - object.left;
    var top = el.top - object.top;    
    var width = el.width;
    var height = el.height;    
    object.clipTo = function (ctx) {  
        ctx.rect(-(width/2)+left, -(height/2)+top,    parseInt(width*el.scaleX), parseInt(height*el.scaleY)); 
    }   
    canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject(el));
    lastActive = object;
    canvas.renderAll(); 
    left = 0;
    top = 0;
}
function startCropEl(){
    canvas.remove(el);
    if(canvas.getActiveObject()) {
        object=canvas.getActiveObject();
        el = new fabric.Ellipse({
        fill: 'transparent',
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        stroke: 'yellow',
        strokeDashArray: [5, 4],
        rx: object.width/3,
        ry: object.width/3,
        opacity: 1,
        borderColor: '#36fd00',
        cornerColor: 'green',
        hasRotatingPoint:false,
        objectCaching: false
    });  
    el.left=canvas.getActiveObject().left;
    el.top=canvas.getActiveObject().top;
    el.width=canvas.getActiveObject()
        .width*canvas.getActiveObject().scaleX;
    el.height=canvas.getActiveObject()
        .height*canvas.getActiveObject().scaleY;    
    canvas.add(el);
    canvas.setActiveObject(el);
    } else {
    alert("Please select an object or layer");
    }
}
function endCropEl(){
    var left = el.left - object.left;
    var top = el.top - object.top;
    var width = el.rx;
    var height = el.ry;   
    object.clipTo = function (ctx) {
        if ((parseInt(width*el.scaleX) === width ||   
            parseInt(height*el.scaleY) === width) && 
            (top === 0 && left === 0)) {        
            ctx.ellipse(left, top, parseInt(width*el.scaleX),
                parseInt(height*el.scaleY), 45 * Math.PI/180, 0, 
                2 * Math.PI);  
        } 
        else {           
            ctx.ellipse(-(width/2)+left, -(height/2)+top,
                parseInt(width*el.scaleX),
                parseInt(height*el.scaleY), 
                45 * Math.PI/180, 0, 2 * Math.PI);    
        }
    }
    canvas.remove(canvas.getActiveObject(el));
    lastActive = object;
    canvas.renderAll();
    left = 0;
    top = 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Image Cropping with Fabric</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div id="bd-wrapper" >
           <h2>Cropping with Fabric</h2>
           <canvas id="c" width="600" height="560" style="border: 1px dashed grey;"></canvas><br/>
           <div class="controls" id="text-controls-additional">
               <h3>Rectangle Crop</h3>
               <button class="btn" id="startCropRect">Start Crop</button> 
               <button class="btn" id="endCropRect">End Crop</button> 
               <h3>Circle Crop</h3>
               <button class="btn" id="startCropEl">Start Crop</button> 
               <button class="btn" id="endCropEl">End Crop</button> 
               <h3>Undo/Redo for both</h3>
               <button class="btn" id="undoCrop">Undo Crop</button>
               <button class="btn" id="redoCrop">Redo Crop</button<br />
               <img id="gingerbread-house" style="display:none;" src="images/Gingerbread-House.jpg">
               <img id="pavlova" style="display:none;" src="images/Pavlova.jpg">
           </div>
           <script src="js/script.js"></script>
       </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please share your HTML code as well